# how to find all files of a given extension excluding multiple filename strings

Tags: bash, find, exec

I'm trying to 'find' all files matching "*.gz" and then unpack them but also exclude multiple filename strings.

The current bash string I am using is:

```
find . -name '*.gz' ! -name *dvportgroups* ! -name *nsanity* ! -name *vcsupport* ! -name *viclient* ! -name vsantraces* -exec gunzip -vf {} \;
```

Unfortunately, though this successfully ignores `*dvportgroups*` it still attempts to unpack the other files which I wish to avoid.

This is the same result as when I run:

```
find . -name '*.gz' ! -name *dvportgroups* -exec gunzip -vf {} \;
```

I would like to know how to 'find' all files matching `*.gz` but exclude multiple filename strings.

FWIW this is under bash 4.2 on a machine running RHEL 6.

Comment: You need quotes to prevent shell from expanding the globs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess that many of those files you are trying to exclude have a match in the current directory and therefore need to be quoted.

Try this:

```
find . -name '*.gz' ! -name '*dvportgroups*' ! -name '*nsanity*' ! -name '*vcsupport*' ! -name '*viclient*' ! -name 'vsantraces*' -exec gunzip -vf {} \;
```

If that doesn't work, replace the `-exec ...` with `-print` and see the results more clearly. I just did a similar command (changing only the patterns to match my files and changing `-exec ...` to `-print0`) and it worked fine on my system.

Comment: I used this successfully, with a modification. For some reason I ran into issues passing multiple `! -name 'x'` exclusions and using -exec
instead of using -exec I ended up using:
` while read line; do
        FILNM=$(basename $line)
        DIR2=$(echo $FILNM |sed -e 's/\.tgz$//')
    if [ -d $DIR2 ];then
        echo "$line already unzipped, skipping"
    else
        mkdir $DIR2
                echo "unpacking $line into ./$DIR2"
        tar -xzf $line -C ./$DIR2
    fi
done
`